# Laravel/Ajax CRUD: show option value on edit button click

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, crud, edit

I have an edit modal with three drop down select options

[image: 1]

Currently having trouble showing the appropriate option on edit button click, my input fields have no issue.

heres my working add function for reference, all three option tags are working in this way.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.add_category', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var category_data = {
                'category_name': $('.category_name').val(),
                'category_description': $('.category_description').val(),
                'category_description': $('.category_description').val(),
                'config_view_type': $('.config_view_type').val(),
                'config_edit_type': $('.config_edit_type').val(),
                'bbrmode_view_type': $('.bbrmode_view_type').val(),
            }
            
            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration",
                data: category_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                if(response.status == 400) {
                    $('#category_formCheck').html("");
                    $('#category_formCheck').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                    $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values) {
                        $('#category_formCheck').append('<li>'+err_values+'</li>');
                    });
                    }
                else  
                  {
                    $('#category_notif').html("");
                    $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                    $('#createCategory').modal('hide');
                    fetchcategory();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

also, in my edit category button, I went ahead and used console.log to show that the option values can be read form the table:

[image: 2]

I tried to add the three in my edit display

```
        $(document).on('click','.edit_category',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $(this).val();
            console.log(cat_id);
            $('#editCategoryModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-edit/"+cat_id,
                success: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == 404) {
                        $('#success_message').html("");
                        $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $('#success_message').text(response.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#edit_category_name').val(response.category_edit.category_name);
                        $('#edit_category_description').val(response.category_edit.category_description);
                        $('#edit_cat_id').val(response.category_edit.category_id);
                        
//new code     
                           
$('#edit_config_view_type').val(response.category_edit.config_view_typ);
                                
$('#edit_config_edit_type').val(response.category_edit.config_edit_type);
                                
$('#edit_bbrmode_view_type').val(response.category_edit.bbrmode_view_type);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

modal fields:

```
                            <input type="text" id="edit_category_name" class="form-control form-group w-100" placeholder="Category Name">
                            <textarea id="edit_category_description" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Category Description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row mb-4">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <small class="font-weight-bold">Config Access View Type:</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="edit_config_view_type" class="edit_config_view_type form-control w-100" name="config_view">
                                            {{-- <option id="edit_category_name" class="form-control form-group w-100" value="asdasd"></option> --}}
                                            
                                        <option>Public</option>
                                        <option>Restricted</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                    <button id="edit_config_view_type_r" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new_category"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle "></i> Add Recipient</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

tried adding `<option id="edit_config_view_type" ></option>` but to no avail.

Notes:

- have the option value show up in the edit button like the name/description textfields.
- the option needs to be the same as the column values from the table.
- `category_name` and `category_description` are already read from the table, I just need to have that effect on a dropdown
- also added a shortcut on the three columns when added: P & R and they get displayed as Public and restricted

This question is a bit on the advice side, any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hi, are you using any plugin for select-box ? Also, if response is is `P` so public option should be selected?

Comment: @Swati no plugins and yes P is Public R is restricted

Comment: Did you resolve this or not ?